# How to get controller and action names of MVC project out of itself

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Trying to get controller and action names out of presentation layer, like in infrastructure layer as a service. I can get the assembly this way but when filtering like code below on it, I am getting null

```
public class ControllerActionDiscoveryService : 
                 IControllerActionDiscoveryService
{

public ControllerActionDiscoveryService(Type[] assembly)
{
    
}

public List<ControllerActionInfo> Discover()
{
    // Load the assembly using the correct path
    var assemblyPath = @".../Server.dll";
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);

    var controllerTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.IsClass==true && type.FullName.Contains("Controller"));

    foreach (var controllerType in controllerTypes)
    {
        // Do something with each controller type
        Console.WriteLine(controllerType.FullName);
    }
}
}
```

If someone knows better way to get assembly of MVC project, share it please.

with this code I can get the controller but I can not get the actions. Is it because the information in assembly convert to text file?

with this kind of filtering I got null.

```
var controllerTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.BaseType==typeof(ControllerBase));
```

The result sample without using `Where()`: `Server.Controllers.HomeController Server.Areas.Dashboard.Controllers.FileManagerController Server.Areas.Dashboard.Controllers.HomeController`

Comment: Perhaps the base type is not `Controller`, but [`ControllerBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase)...? It seems that a more appropriate test would be `type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Controller))`.

Comment: `var controllerTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.IsClass==true && type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Controller)));`
 I used this code, yet null result has returned. @SimonMᶜKenzie

Comment: You got null, or you got an empty collection? Maybe it would help you debug if you just write out all the types from that assembly, without filters. Is there _anything_ in there?

Comment: I got "Count = 0". It can not filter on it. I added `ToList()` also:  `var controllerTypes = assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.IsClass==true && type.BaseType==typeof(ControllerBase)).ToList();` @SimonMᶜKenzie

Comment: When I say "without filters", I mean take out the Where, just so you can see what types are available from that assembly.

Comment: It is ok without `Where()` and also this code work in MVC project but out of that is not working. This is the sample without `Where()`; `AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Areas_Dashboard_Views_FileManager_Index
AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Areas_Dashboard_Views_FileManager_PartialViews__DisplayControls
`@SimonMᶜKenzie

Comment: Maybe you're loading the wrong assembly

Comment: I just copy and paste this code to one of controller and result was ok. this is the sample: `{Name = "BaseController" FullName = "Server.Infrastructure.BaseController"}` and `{Name = "HomeController" FullName = "Server.Controllers.HomeController"}`. I can do any filter on it easily. @SimonMᶜKenzie

Comment: _If someone knows better way to get assembly_

2 possible solutions that might help:
* Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() -> gets the assembly where the current code belongs to
* typeof(string).Assembly -> Example of how to get the assembly, where a type comes from (string is just an example of course)

Comment: Thanks. But these are good ways. but Still I got the same result and also about the `typeof(some class in MVC project).assembly`, it can not be used in Infrastructure, because we have reference from infrastructure in MVC project, so we can not access its classes due to circular dependency. @RonaldKorze